# Which distributions of $X$ and $Y$ yield a Gaussian $Z=XY$?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Let $Z=XY$ where $X$, $Y$ are random variables with support of non-trivial measure. For what distributions of $X$ and $Y$ can $Z$ be guaranteed to be Gaussian?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible if X and Y are independent. If they are dependent it’s easy of course: just take a Gaussian R and any distribution for Y and then define X=R/Y.

Comment: How about the Box-Muller transform? The Gaussian-generating interaction can come from how one plays with functions and domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was shown in [this paper (see formula (2) there)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09838v1) that any normal random variable (r.v.) $Z$ is multiplicatively infinitely divisible; that is, for each natural $k$ there exist iid r.v.'s $W_1,\dots,W_k$ such that $Z$ equals $W_1\cdots W_k$ in distribution; the distribution of $W_1$ is explicitly described.

From that description, it is easy to get an entire continuous one-parameter family $\big((X_t,Y_t)\big)_{t\in(0,1)}$ of pairs $(X_t,Y_t)$ of nontrivial independent r.v.'s such that $X_tY_t$ has the (say) standard normal distribution for each $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. The $W_i$´s seem difficult to construct though.

Comment: @rodms The $W_i$'s are not so difficult to approximate using finite sums, see the Example section of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3818660/133843, where the r.v.'s are approximated in Python using the NumPy library.

Comment: @Witiko : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you for the result. I will cite your preprint in a work that deals with the initialization of neural network weights, where the product of several iid r.v.'s must have standard normal distribution.

Comment: @Witiko : I am glad this was of help.

Comment: @IosifPinelis As promised, the following preprint makes use of your result and additionally proves some properties useful for the initialization of weights in neural networks (see appendix A.3): https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.09691v5. The camera-ready is to appear in the International Journal of Universal Computer Science (J.UCS) 28:2 this February.

Comment: @Witiko : Thank you for letting me know. I am glad this was of use.